# Mockito Junit on a reference object

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am facing a strange problem while trying to unit test my code.

Here is my code :

```
public class ItemService {

    private OfferService offerService;

    @Inject
    public ItemService (OfferService offerService){
        this.offerService = offerService;
    }

    public List<Item> buildItems(ItemInfo itemInfo) {
        List<Item> items = processItem(itemInfo);
        Offers<Offer> offers = fetchItemInfo(items);

        // based on the object offers, do some processing
    }


    private Offers<Offer> fetchItemInfo(List<Item> items) {
            Offers<Offer> offers = new Offers<>();
            // some processing here with offers.
            // calling the db to fetch details 
            offerService.fetchInfoFromDB(offers);
            return offers;
    }
}

public class OfferService {
    public void fetchInfoFromDB(Offers<Offer> offers) {
        // fetching details from DB
        // and updating the object **offers**
        myDao.getDetailsById(id);
    }
}
```

Now I have written junit to test the method **buildItems()**

**UPDATE** updating the mocks used and mock injection.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ItemService.class)
public class ItemServiceTest{

    @Mock private MyDAO myDao;
    @Mock private OfferService offerService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        ItemService  itemService = new ItemService (offerService, myDao);

    }

    public void testBuildItems(){
        // some code -----
        itemInfo = buildItemInfo();
        offerDetail = buildOfferDetail();
        when(myDao.getDetailsById(Mockito.anyLong())).thenReturn(offerDetail);

        // some code -----
        // I need to implement some code which will actually call
        // offerService.fetchInfoFromDB(offers);
        // and update the --offers-- object and return it.
        List<Item> items = itemService.buildItems(itemInfo);
        Assert.assertNotNull(items);
    }
    
}
```

I am running with coverage and I can see that the below line got executed but the actual method is not getting called :

```
offerService.fetchInfoFromDB(offers);
```

I am getting null values in **offers**. Then I added the below line :

```
doCallRealMethod().when(offerService).fetchInfoFromDB(offers);
```

Still the same result. The **offers** object is passed by reference and is getting updated after the DB call which I am mocking already. But upto that call my code is not reaching. How can I update the **offers**  object in my junit. Please help.

Comment: Can you please tell what your `List<Item> items = processItem(itemInfo)` returning while you debug? Secondly offerService is a dependency in the class but i dont see it being injected or initialized.

Comment: @JeffBowman : Can you please help. Got to you through this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27421417/modify-input-parameter-of-a-void-function-and-read-it-afterwards/27432585

Comment: Comment replies by name [only notify with users who interact with the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work). Mentioning me by name doesn't work unless I've already posted here. Your comment on my question did work, but asking a specific user for help is [not appropriate behavior on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/is-it-ethical-to-contact-a-user-to-draw-their-attention-to-a-question-where-the). Finally, you can edit my other question into the body text here; it helps answerers to know what you've seen and tried.

Comment: As Deb Das noted, you haven't actually shown us your test setup where you populate `itemService.offerService` with a mock OfferService, and in fact your mock in your test is `myDao` rather than any Service at all. Without that additional context, I don't think there is enough information here to diagnose your problem.

Comment: @JeffBowman : Hi .. Thanks for replying. I have updated the mocks in my test class. Can you check now please. Even though `offerService` I am mocking but I cant use it properly.

Answer (score 2):

Your test is calling a zero arg `ItemService()` constructor, not the one arg `@Inject` constructor you posted. Either your code won't compile, or you haven't actually shown us the code in question.

Also, you say you are mocking `offerService`:

1. You call `when` on `myDao` and not `offerService`,
2. you do not pass your mock `offerService` into your `ItemService` constructor, as in `new ItemService(offerService)`, and
3. your `doCallRealMethod` won't work because your mock `offerService` won't use your mock `myDao`; you'll need to mock the call on `offerService` directly with a `thenAnswer` that changes the passed `List<Offer>`, as on [my question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27432585/1426891).

   ```
    doAnswer(invocation -> {
       ((List<Offer>) invocation.getArgument(0)).add(offerDetail);
       return null;
    }).when(offerService).fetchInfoFromDb(any());
   ```

If you fix those three you will be considerably closer to a working test.

Comment: I am not using zero arg . Its initializing the required fields. I was not able to call `when` on `offerService` as it was not returning anything. Only the object was getting updated based on some validations. Now what I am doing is trying to mock the private method call  `fetchItemInfo` using PowerMockito and I could control the object. My purpose is solved. But still I am unable to use the `doAnswer` or `thenAnswer`. Can you help me in that please as I dont want to mock private methods.

Comment: Also I dont want to test the method  `fetchItemInfo()`. I want to test the method `buildItems()` which needs the output from `fetchItemInfo()` as based on that output I have different scenarios to test.

Comment: @Som Thank you for updating your constructor to be more accurate. You are right to avoid mocking `fetchItemInfo`, not just because it is a private method, but also because it is a part of your system under test. I'll update with a `doAnswer` attempt, but you may need to correct it, as I am not at a proper computer to test.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! let me try it out .. I will let you know surely.