# How to test void method with Mockito's doAnswer

Tags: android, junit, mockito

I am new to Mockito and trying to understand how to use `doAnswer` in order to test a *void* method.

Here's my class with the `onDestroy` method to test:

```
public class TPresenter implements TContract.Presenter {
    private CompositeSubscription viewSubscription;

    //.......

    @Override public void onCreate(.......) {
        this.viewSubscription = new CompositeSubscription();
        //.......
    }

    @Override public void onDestroy() {
        if(viewSubscription != null && !viewSubscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
            viewSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Now I want to write a test for `onDestroy()` namely to verify that after executing `onDestroy` the subscription is unsubscribed. I found several examples to use `doAnswer` for testing *void* methods, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429169/how-to-mock-a-void-return-method-affecting-an-object), and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223596/mocking-void-methods-using-mockito) but I do not understand them.

Please show how to test the method `onDestroy`.

Comment: @GhostCat Please se my comment to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The normal way how you could test your `onDestroy()` would be based on `viewSubscription` being a mocked object. And then you would do something like:

```
@Test
public testOnDestroyWithoutUnsubscribe() {
  when(mockedSubscription.isUnsubscribed()).thenReturn(false);
  //... trigger onDestroy()
  verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockedSubscription);
}

@Test
public testOnDestroyWithUnsubscribe() {
  when(mockedSubscription.isUnsubscribed()).thenReturn(true);
  //... trigger onDestroy()
  verify
  verify(mockedSubscription, times(1)).unsubscribe();
}
```

In other words: you create a mocked object, and you configure it to take both paths that are possible. Then you verify that the expected actions took place (or not, that is what the first test case does: ensure you do not unsubscribe).

Of course, you can't test the "subscription object is null" case (besides making it null, and ensuring that no NPE gets thrown when triggering the `onDestroy()`!

Given the comment by the OP: one doesn't necessarily have to use mocking here. But when you want to test a void method, your options are pretty limited. You have to observe side effects somehow!

If you **can** get a non-mocked viewSubscription instance to do that, fine, then do that. But if not, then *somehow* inserting a mocked instance is your next best choice. How to do the "dependency injection" depends on the exact context, such as the mocking/testing frameworks you are using.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but why do I need to mock the viewSubscription which is a private instance of my class TPresenter? I thought private instances of the class under test are real objects and are not mocked.

Comment: I tried but the tests do not pass. It seems that the method onDestroy is un-testable because viewSubscription is instantiated in onCreate.

Comment: @Monica Well, the "problem" here is the call to new. You can either user PowerMock(ito) to work around that, or you change to some other form of dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

Testing void methods in your main class under test is not a problem as does not require doAnswer.

Here is an example of how could you go about testing the call to unsubscribe.

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.never;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;


@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TPresenterTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private TPresenter target = new TPresenter();

    @Mock
    private CompositeSubscription viewSubscription;


    @Test
    public void onDestroyShouldUnsubscribeWhenSubscriptionNotNullAndUnsubscribed() {
        when(viewSubscription.isUnsubscribed()).thenReturn(false);

        target.onDestroy();

        verify(viewSubscription).unsubscribe();
    }

    @Test
    public void onDestroyShouldNotUnsubscribeWhenSubscriptionNotNullAndNotUnsubscribed() {
        when(viewSubscription.isUnsubscribed()).thenReturn(true);

        target.onDestroy();

        verify(viewSubscription, never()).unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I have the same question: why do I need to mock the viewSubscription which is a private instance of my class TPresenter?

Comment: The viewSubscription class is providing your class under test (TPresenter) with some functionality. From point of view of TPresenter is an external dependency. You don't need to mock it but it is sometimes just easier. Especially when there is some kind of logic of operation performed in your dependency. e.g. if your dependency is a service then it might be much easier to just mock it and to not execute actual body of it. If it is a POJO, on another hand, then you might choose just to instantiate it and set its fields.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment to @GhostCat 's answer, my example is in fact un-testable because of the "new" instance of CompositeSubscription class. I would have to re-factor it and @GhostCat 's comment to his/her answer shows a way to do it.